# My IOS orientation acting very strange and won't listen to any programing-code?

Tags: ios, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, portrait, info-plist

As the title describes I am having a big "what the ***** is this" at my app atm. It seems I can't get the control over the orientation at all in the different slides.
I can only manage the orientation in one way, via the info-plist file. The problem is, info-plist file sets the orientation for the whole app and I am not interested in that.In some slides I want to allow Landscape left/right and others only Portrait and this is not doable vie info-plist?

I have tried my best to understand the problem but I can not say I have gained any bigger "aha moment" so far. I am using UINavigatorbar and Tabbar in my IOS-app which may occur the problem. How can I make the app to start listening to the code in each-file so I can manage the orientation localy ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using iOS 6?  If so, the `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method was deprecated.

You now have to override `-supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `-preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` methods in order to manage screen orientation.  You can do this globally or within individual view controllers.

See the [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a) for more details.